# On screen keyboard shortcut

Tags: touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

I use a 2in1 convertible.
Usually, when i switch the device into tablet mode, the On Screen Keyboard activated.

Except sometimes it does not. And when it refuses to open up, the workflow for me always is:

```
Take device out of stand
Flip to Landscape mode
Flip out keyboard
Press some keys
Revert everything
```

Which is a huge pain.

Is there any option to add an On Screen Keyboard button to the taskbar somehow?

Comment: In earlier versions of Ubuntu, swiping up from the bottom of the screen would bring up the on-screen keyboard but that no longer appears to work on Ubuntu 22.04, so some other control for forcing the on-screen keyboard to appear would be very useful.